# Losing application Name from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis

I am using IIS to host an internal site. I have used visual studio express for web.

The problem I am having is when try to go to another part of the web site it drops the application name I have given it in IIS

Example:

www.name.com/applicationName/Home (this is whats working)

after trying to move to another part of the site the url becomes

www.name.com/Home/showDevice?sendmsg=192.168.0.1 (This does not work)

if I add the /applicationName/ to the above url it works correctly.

Is this and IIS issue I need to configure or is there something in the code I need to fix.

Comment: Did you created sub-domain virtual directory(i.e., applicationName) under default website?

Comment: Yes. I did.  I have it under the default website.

Comment: do you have any webHttpBinding in your applicationName(VirtualDirectory)?

Comment: No, I do not it is empty.

Comment: If your applicationName is main project, you no need to create sub domain(Virtual directory) under default website. Just publish from your project, your Publish  profile's Service URL should be localhost and Site/Application should be : "Default Web Site"

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The problem was that I had it under the default website and added it as a sub page. I disable the default website and add it as its own website with the default 80 port and it is working perfect now. Thanks